# Macbook Pro's Broadcom B4322 wifi driver for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, broadcom, b43

I am setting up a 16.04 installation on an old Macbook pro with a Broadcom B4322 (14e4:432b).

As this hasn't worked out of the box I've tried installing other drivers:

- bcmwl-kernel-source
- firmware-b43-installer
- broadcom-sta-common

Installing these packages had no effect.

```
$ sudo lshw -c network

  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:d3200000-d3203fff   *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: 10:9a:dd:4a:d0:63
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=5764m-v3.38 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:27 memory:d3100000-d310ffff   *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: f0:b4:79:1c:0d:71
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=b43 driverversion=4.10.0-40-generic firmware=666.2 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11



$rfkill list all 0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no 1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: edit: rather, make sure you have `firmware-b43-installer` installed because from googling it's the firmware your card should work with, then reboot, then post the output of `sudo lshw -c network`.

Comment: And also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've just added to the question the results of the commands you have asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered that bcmwl-kernel-source works after having suspended the the system.